# geode-junit 1.8.0 pom depends on non-existent geode-old-versions artifact

Tags: junit, geode

I thought I might try out the GfshRule provided by geode-junit 1.8.0, but its pom contains a dependency on an apparently non-existent artifact called `geode-old-versions` so my Maven-based project won't build. Please advise. Thanks

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.geode</groupId>
  <artifactId>geode-old-versions</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, already reported through [GEODE-6105](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-6105). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in Geode 1.10.0, through [GEODE-6105](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-6105).

Cheers.